# Best resources to self-educate myself in economics

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, finance, investment, money

I want to learn Economics by myself and I'm looking to build a path with people who're in this field to how and in what order should I learn Economics, I did some research and I've found many resources to learn from and I'm sure all of the information could be helpful to me in the future but I'm quite sure that not all of the material is practical. I'm ready to invest as many hours and buy all of the books required in-order to learn the material but there's just one thing to keep in mind in this path that I'm asking you to help me build which is: Practicality of the material and how fast I could start to use this knowledge to do trial and error to maximize my learning with the available resources of money I currently have.

Comment: What kind of Economics do you want to learn? What's your education so far? Have you consulted study guides of good universities? This might be a good start: http://www.londoninternational.ac.uk/sites/default/files/programme_resources/lse/lse_pdf/subject_guides/ec1002_ch1-4.pdf

Comment: The three main pillars of economics are: Microeconomics, Macroeconomics and Econometrics. For network stumblers: A lot of economics' students underestimate the use of Mathematics. Sydsaeter and Hammond with their two books have made a great job on that. http://www.amazon.com/Essential-Mathematics-Economic-Analysis-3rd/dp/0273713248/ & http://www.amazon.com/Further-Mathematics-Economic-Analysis-Edition/dp/0273713280

Answer (score 5):

If I'm to give a single reference on learning six years of economics by yourself, it would be

### MIT Economics Course

- http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/economics/

The MIT has the best graduate economic program, and its undergrad program is definitely in the top 3. The faculty is technical-oriented, which means a lot of math, so you'll be well prepared.

The list of requirements included in a syllabus of each course says what other courses you must complete before approaching this one. So, you'll know your learning path in advance.

Each course includes lecture notes and recommended literature.

I'd also keep in mind that while you save money learning this way, the process is quite difficult (especially due to solving math problems alone) and puts you out of sync with institutional aspects of formal education. Like, it's harder to enroll in a grad program or get an advantage in employment.